# infinite dimensional funtional ito calculus

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, functional-calculus

I've been reading into functional Ito calculus and everything I've come across deals with processes generated by *finite* dimensional semimartingales. In Dupire's 2009 [landmark paper](https://www.aims.ac.za/assets/files/Finance/Bruno%20Dupire%20Slide%203%20(Paper).pdf) he speaks about possible future extension to the infinite dimensional case.

My question is *is there and where can I find a text dealing with a functional Ito calculus based on processes generated by infinite dimensional semimartingales*?

Any references are very much appreciated, thanks.